# Why am i getting Failed to bind to 3X.XXX.X.X:[9300-9400], while securing my cluster with SSL/TLS

Tags: elasticsearch, https

I was following [this blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/configuring-ssl-tls-and-https-to-secure-elasticsearch-kibana-beats-and-logstash) to encrypt communication of my Elasticsearch Cluster,

I am getting the following error, when i try to start my Elasticsearch using

**sudo systemctl start elasticsearch**

I am using a GCP server which has port exposed (9215) and (5601) .

```
[2020-10-13T02:18:40,800][WARN ][o.e.g.DanglingIndicesState] [myNode1] gateway.auto_import_dangling_indices is disabled, dangling indices will not be automatically detected or imported and must be managed manually
[2020-10-13T02:18:41,272][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [myNode1] initialized
[2020-10-13T02:18:41,273][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [myNode1] starting ...
[2020-10-13T02:18:41,505][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] [myNode1] Exception
org.elasticsearch.transport.BindTransportException: Failed to bind to 3X.XXX.X.X:[9300-9400]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.bindToPort(TcpTransport.java:408) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.bindServer(TcpTransport.java:372) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport.doStart(Netty4Transport.java:130) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.security.transport.netty4.SecurityNetty4Transport.doStart(SecurityNetty4Transport.java:84) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.netty4.SecurityNetty4ServerTransport.doStart(SecurityNetty4ServerTransport.java:46) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:59) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.doStart(TransportService.java:233) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:59) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.start(Node.java:778) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:317) ~[elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:402) [elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) [elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:161) [elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) [elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:127) [elasticsearch-cli-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) [elasticsearch-cli-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:126) [elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) [elasticsearch-7.9.2.jar:7.9.2]
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:550) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:249) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:134) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:550) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:506) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:491) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:973) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:248) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:356) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[?:?]
```

it seems elasticsearc is trying to connect to a port in range [9300-9400] but since these ports are not exposed, it is trowing error.

Following is my */etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml* file

```
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
cluster.name: myCluster1
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
node.name: myNode1
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#

# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
network.host: myNode1.elastic.test.com
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
http.port: 9215
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
discovery.seed_hosts: ["myNode1.elastic.test.com"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["myNode1"]


# ------------------------------Enabling Security ------------------------------
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.key: certs/myNode1.key
xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate: certs/myNode1.crt
xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities: certs/ca.crt
xpack.security.transport.ssl.key: certs/myNode1.key
xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate: certs/myNode1.crt
xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities: certs/ca.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

The `9300-9400` range is used for the TCP `transport` communication, which is how the nodes communicate with each other, clients communicate using **HTTP**, which uses the range `9200-9299`, or in your case, `9215`.

Since you set `network.host` to `0.0.0.0`, elasticsearch will try to bind both the **HTTP** and the **TCP** endpoints to every IP address in your instance, and it seems that it cannot bind to a port in the range `9300-9400` for the `transport` endpoint.

It looks like you have only one node, so you can remove the `xpack.security.transport.*` lines from your config file and you need to remove the `network.host` from your config and use `http.host` instead, this will make elasticsearch to only bind the **HTTP** endpoint to your `3X.*.*.*` ip address, the transport will bind to a loopback address, and you also need to have `discovery.type: single-node`.

Your `elasticsearch.yml` should be something like this:

```
cluster.name: myCluster1
node.name: myNode1
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
http.host: myNode1.elastic.test.com
http.port: 9215
discovery.type: single-node
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["myNode1"]
# security
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.key: certs/myNode1.key
xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate: certs/myNode1.crt
xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities: certs/ca.crt
```

If you have more than one node or are planning to add more nodes in the future, you will need to allow another port for the internode communicaton.